# Error Message: "A reboot is pending. Please restart before starting Visual Studio

Tags: reboot, visual-studio-2015

Error Message:

> "A reboot is pending. Please restart before starting Visual Studio".

I installed Visual Studio (Visual Basic 2015 and SQL 2015) and after what looked like a successful install I then got the "Reboot" window.

Not expecting it I had a bunch of things open. So I closed a bunch a bunch of things, and did the reboot myself.

Now I cannot run Visual Basic because it ONLY gives me the above error message in the pop-up window. It won't even let me do a re-install.

All it does is keep giving me the above error message.

If you have any advice that's better than a complete uninstall/reinstall I'm sure everyone in my situation would benefit from it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure this answer is no longer reliant to OP but for any other people with this problem instead of selecting the '**Shut Down**' option use the '**Restart**' one.  Apparently there is a difference between the two when it comes to installing updates (which in this instance is whatever Visual Studio needs to do to finish installing).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after installing **VS2015 Update 1** on **Windows 10**.

I went to System Settings → Windows Update Settings → Clicked the **Restart** button which caused my computer to restart and apply **pending** windows updates.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after installing Exchange Server; and while I know it's not the same problem you're having, it put me into a continual pending reboot pattern.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164360(v=exchg.80).aspx

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations
```

I had to delete this key in order to continue the reboot and make everything work. The actual steps are listed in the technet article I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods:

- Use   [**Ignore-Restart.bat**](https://puvox.software/blog/visual-studio-needs-to-be-restarted/) script to temporarily override "restart" requirement.

or

- Restart PC (not shutdown)

Comment: The link is now dead, making this answer completely useless. Wayback machine has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In the registry...search for "rebootreq" - it should come up with one or more keys that have RebootRequired in it. Delete those (keep F3ing till it stops finding more). That should do the trick.